# IONIC Framework - Form Layout

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm learning how to use the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/). I like a lot of it. However, I don't care for the form layouts. I would really like to include one additional component: some help text. In other words, I would like to create a form tht looks like the following:

```
Label1
[TextBox with a border here]
a tidbit goes here

Label2
[TextBox with a border here]
a tidbit goes here.

[Button]
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this well in the Ionic Framework. All of the form layouts use a list, which adds boundaries to each piece, which I don't want. Can a CSS wizard please help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: If any of the answers are correct, you should mark them as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How does this work?](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/FgLeG) for you?

```
       <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label item-divider">
          Name

        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
          </label>

        <div class="item item-footer">
          Please enter your name
        </div>
```

To get the css the way you want, you can add this

```
.item{
  border: none;
}
.item-footer {
  font-size:11px ;
  padding: 8px ;
}

.item-stacked-label input, .item-stacked-label textarea{
  padding:0 ;
}
```

Comment: That HTML snippet isn't correct: there's a </div> in the <label>.

Comment: Typically you'd use <label FOR="theID"...>text</label><input id="theID"...>  This gives you more flexibility in styling.

Comment: Not really the way that ionic is handling it. If the label is tapped, it will set target the any input that is within the label.